# How to differ from writing exception to a reading one?

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, ioexception

I have a socket and I'd like to send messages and read from it.

When I read/write with the socket while the other side is offline, I get the same Exception: `System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation on non-blocking socket would block`.

How can I identify in which of the two it happened besides having two separate try-catch blocks? Can't I just get a `Timeout Exception` when the reading timeout is over?

example:

```
try
{
    SendData("!GetLocation!");
    string data = GetData();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is System.IO.IOException)
        {
            //How can I identify if the exception was raised at the read method or the write method?
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in which of the two it happened"?

Comment: Why dont you have two separate try-catch blocks?

Comment: I could, but that doesn't look good. I'm just trying to understand further, I didn't say that I won't get along without it..

Comment: One question is whether you need to know which one threw the exception. Will you do something different? If you do need to distinguish between the two then separate try/catches are the way to go. Also, instead of the `if` you can have multiple catches with one try. First catch `IoException`, and then if you need to catch more general exceptions catch `Exception`. Often we need less of this than we think. Sometimes we don't need any try/catch in a method and the exception handling in outer methods is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, exception handling is heavy resource wise, but sometimes is not so bad.

If you stick to only one try-catch you can check the error message.

Note: I have also added a second try-catch for generic (non IO) errors

```
try
{
    SendData("!GetLocation!");
    string data = GetData();
}
catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.IndexOf("Unable to read") != -1)
    {
     // GetData error
    }
    else if (ex.Message.IndexOf("Unable to write") != -1)
    {
     // SendData error
    }
    else
    {
       //Other IO errors
    }

}
catch(Exception exc)
{
    // Unspected errors
}
```

you could also set a boolean variable and check its value to know where it 
broke your code.

```
bool sendCalled = false;

try
{
    SendData("!GetLocation!");
    sendCalled = true;
    string data = GetData();
}
catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
{
    if (sendCalled)
    {
     // GetData error
    }
    else
    {
     // SendData error
    }
}
```

Comment: Correction: You're not comparing the result of `ex.Message.IndexOf(...)` to a value.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks a lot. One more thing please- Why can't I raise a TimeOut Exception if the read function exceeds it's given recieve timeout?

Comment: Plus I'd like to get an explanation about the comparison of `ex.Message.IndexOf(...)` to `-1`..

Comment: Comparing `IndexOf` to -1 is basically saying "subject string does not contain specified substring". You could also do `!ex.Message.Contains(...)`, which is more modern and readable.

Comment: @DanielReyhanian String.IndexOf [returns -1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_) if no match is found.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. But again, why don't I get a Timeout Exception?

Comment: About the Timeout exception... Do your methods raise that kind of exception? Something like `if (time_passed_check) throw new TimeoutException("I waited too much!");`

Answer (score 1):

Not that I endorse either of these solutions, but an answer is an answer: you can either

- analyze the stack trace of the exception to find out which call failed (e.g. name of the method at the top of the stack frame
- set a flag after the write, and do logic based on that flag

Neither of these is as straight forward as wrapping each method call. In fact, wrapping each call conveys your intent. In the `catch` of your first call, you can return/break/skip the read call, which explicitly tells the reader you're bailing out fast.